# How to get Shortcode attribute values in custom template page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, templates, attributes, shortcode

Need help :
I made a cutom shortcode in wordpress plugin and pasted that code in Add new Page like this.

[test-shortcode attr=test]

i have defined attribute called attr and given its value "test" in the page. Now i made a custom Page template for that page.

My Question is how can i get the value of "attr" attribute in that new template ?

Is there any function exists or some technique to do this?

Thanks
Waiting for answer

Comment: Please post your shortcode rendering function.

Comment: I just defined a shortcode like this

function createOP($code){
    echo $code['code'].' with kamal ';
}

add_shortcode("op","createOP");

and then past the shortcode on the wordpress page like this [op code=12322443]

I want the value of code which is 12322443 to show in a new custom template i am making for that page,

Answer (score -3):

use below code in your custom page

```
echo do_shortcode( '[gallery]' );
```

Hope this helps. Cheers;)